# Python argparse: using a metavar with square brackets?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to implement a set of program positional arguments, all in the form of `[FOO:]BAR`, where `FOO` part is optional and delimited from the `BAR` part by a `:`.

The reason I cannot and also do not want to use options like `--foo FOO` is that there are multiple positional arguments in the aforementioned form, so `--foo` optional arguments would be highly ambiguous, thus not working.

Now, using a `metavar="[FOO:]BAR"` triggers some obscure runtime error in argparse. Besides resorting to Unicode glyphs bearing some remote resemblence with square brackets (such as `⟦FOO:⟧BAR`) is there any other (preferably better) way to sneak in plain "[]" square brackets into metavars? I would like to give my users a clear understanding of how these positional arguments work.

Comment: Characters like `[]` do give the current formatter problems.  It's a known issue.  A patch for that has been added to the next Python release.  But for now, you'll have to find some other notation to convey the desired information.

Comment: The relevant bug/issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue11874

Comment: @hpaulj thank you very much for the bug report link; so your correct answer would basically be "angle brackets should work now with the fix"? If yes, I would happily accept this as a full answer to my question, after you or I could check that the landed patch does in fact cover my situation.